# Installation of Xamarin in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have Visual Studio Professional 2013 installed in windows 8.1 and have a requirement for cross platform development.

Can we know how to set up xamarin with VS Professional 2013 in windows 8.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check here

1. Univeral Installer
   https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/
2. Manual Installation
   https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/

Comment: If I proceed with above setup, does this support cross platform mobile development.

Comment: Yes , but iOS Simulator you need Mac pc

Answer (score 0):

Please, keep in mind that on Windows one can develop only for Android and Windows platforms. If you want to develop for IOS, you would need a Mac. You may still develop in VS, but it will run on a connected Mac. See https://www.xamarin.com/visual-studio

Apart from that, there is nothing special with installing Xamarin as part of Visual studio. On xamarin web-site you have VS plugin, which among others will download and install Android SDK and tools for you (you may need to register with xamarin.com in order to download it)

Good luck!